How to use differential entropy as pre-processing?
I am currently working on implementing the model EEG_DMNet. For pre-processing it calls for using differential entropy like
$$
h(X) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \log p(x) \, dx
$$
Assuming the Data I am using is gaussian-distributed the formula can be simplified to
$$
h(X) = \frac{1}{2} \log(2\pi e \sigma^2)
$$
My problem is, that I do not understand what "using differential entropy" means. The shape of the input x is $$
x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times C} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times T}
$$
and the output shape should be the same. When trying to add a pre-processing layer in keras, the output shape is not correct.
def call(self, inputs):
     variance = tf.math.reduce_variance(inputs, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
     differential_entropy = 0.5 * tf.math.log(2 * np.pi * np.e * variance)
     return differential_entropy


Maybe they take a sliding-window approach like this paper? For each point in the EEG (for a given channel), crop a window of data, and output a scalar DE. If you slide the window over all of the data, you will end up with an output shape close to the input shape (or the same shape, if you handle the edges). There are papers your study references when describing the DE part - those papers might explain in more detail.
Alternatively, could they compute DE over the timeseries per channel? That would result in a vector of $n_C$ values which could be used to normalise $x$ per channel. Not sure if that makes sense in this domain, as I am not familiar with EEG preprocessing.

I found some more studies(1, 2) that use Differential Entropy and they seem to be using the sliding-window approach. I believe that is the most likely. However I also asked this question here and think the method to maximize differential entropy would also be possible, even though a bit more far stretched.

I see, glad there is now more clarity around that point. When it comes to implementation of a sliding window, you could use pandas.rolling(window=...).apply(calculate_de) if you are familiar with pandas, or alternatively implement a loop that slides a window across the data.
